# Network Based Geofence - .NET

Tags: .net, geofencing

Is it possible to create a Network Based Geofence using the .NET platform?

For example, is there a way where users can "opt in" to a service on their phone without installing anything, that would track when they enter and leave a geofenced area?

Answer (score 0):

On the most primitive level, you need to implement [point-in-polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243042/c-sharp-point-in-polygon) algorythm with regards to your current location in space. Certain specialized RDBMSes (such as PostGIS) have it already implemented via `INSIDE` or `CROSSING` spatial SQL queries.